# Sorting with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, date-sorting

Using XCode 4.6, iOS6, CoreData, UITableViewController, NSFetchesResultsController

I figured out how to get the following dates in to a NSDate variables:

```
todayDate
yesterdayDate
thisWeek
lastWeek
thisMonth
lastMonth
lastYear
```

Now I would like to use NSFetchedResultsController to put the data into sections based on the data in the above variables. I'm assuming I will have to do some date compare:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

There is possibility that some users will not have some of the sections.  **So, I need help with what to put in the following method to determine the number of sections based on the fetchRequest:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

I also need to know how to divide the data into cells `numberOfRowsInSection:` and have it displayed into cells `cellforRowAtIndexPath:`

Some code examples would be nice!  Thanks.

**EDIT**

I haven't integrated the controller yet, but below is the code to fetch:

```
- (void) refreshTable {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Meeting" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastmoddate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *results) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        self.objects = results;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        NSLog(@"An error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }];
```

Here is how I'm getting the dates:

```
   NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

    [components setHour:-[components hour]];
    [components setMinute:-[components minute]];
    [components setSecond:-[components second]];
    NSDate *today = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[[NSDate alloc] init] options:0]; //This variable should now be pointing at a date object that is the start of today (midnight);

    [components setHour:-24];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];
    NSDate *yesterday = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate: today options:0];

    components = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

    [components setDay:([components day] - ([components weekday] - 1))];
    NSDate *thisWeek  = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    [components setDay:([components day] - 7)];
    NSDate *lastWeek  = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    [components setDay:([components day] - ([components day] -1))];
    NSDate *thisMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    [components setMonth:([components month] - 1)];
    NSDate *lastMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: how are you getting your fetch request?

Comment: also how is your data organized? I understand your using Core Data. Are your date variables attributes of a 'user entity'?

Comment: I update the code.  No, the variable are not attributes of an entity.  Thanks.

Comment: so how is each user connected to the dates?

Comment: also, you said you need help implementing (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  because some users might not have some of the sections. Does that mean your going to call - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView separately for each user?

Comment: if you want I can answer the question telling how I would do it. I'll provide the appropriate code, but I think there's a better way using entities and core data that would give your program more functionality and make things a little easier if you have multiple users

Comment: I think I can only call that method once. I believe I have to do the algorithm inside to determine the number of sections.

Comment: Some users might have recently signed up and may not have a history that extends more than a month.

Comment: ok I think I see wat ur trying to do. Basically you want to have a single array, and in that array organize users into separate sections based on how long they have been signed up. Is that correct?

Comment: I think so.  Remember, I also need to know how many cells to provide in each section.

Comment: ok so im going to answer the question, but just so that I havnt misunderstood im going to clarify. Basically the number of sections you are going to have is equal to the number of NSDate varibles you have, but not every user will be added to each section. is that correct because wat you're asking in ur question implies that you're going to have a different UITableVIew for each individual user in which case you would have to call (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView for each user.

Comment: but im assuming you just want one UITableView that has all the users displayed on it. NOT a different UITableView for each user.

Comment: Im out and it's tough to type it out on the phone.  I'll reply in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. Create a core data model and 'user' entity within that model. I assume u know how to do this, but if u dont just comment and ill explain. Then just create a custom class for ur entity like you would with any other entity and give it the lastmoddate NSDate attribute, plus I would add a creationDate attribute which will be equal to the exact date and time of creating the entity so that you can use this as an identifier for each UserEntity. You will also have to have an array of separate arrays for each section you want to create in your UITableView. When you add a user entity to your model, set the attributes, and then because you said some users might not have every variable, set any variable that the user entity doesn't need to nil. When you initialize your arrays just add the user entities who have the appropriate attributes set to a value. Finally, when you implement -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView all you have to do is count the arrays.

Here is what it should look like:

Im going to call the entity that represents each user 'UserEntity' (its NSManagedObject s class will have the same name).

The following code goes in the **header** of which ever class you are going to use to create and fetch entities - it will probably same class you are using to display the UITableView.

```
@interface Class : UITableViewController {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext   *managedObjectContext;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray   *arrayOfArrays;
```

The following code goes in the **implementation** of which ever class you are going to use to create and fetch entities - it will probably same class you are using to display the UITableView.

//for adding the UserEntity to the model (core data database) and setting its attributes

```
- (UserEntity *)addUserEntityToModel {
     UserEntity *myEnt = (UserEntity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

   myEnt.creationDate = [NSDate date];
   myEnt. lastmoddate = ...; //replace the '...' with however you get your date
   //add any other values to the appropriate attributes here, any attributes that do not //pertain to the UserEntity simply ignore - they are automatically set to default when they //are created.

    NSError *error = nil;
    if(!managedObjectContext) 
        NSLog(@"managedObejctContext problem at ...");
    else if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"context not saved!");;
    } else 
    NSLog(@"context successfully saved.");      
}
```

//for getting the UserEntity's

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getFetchArray {

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        if(!managedObjectContext) {
            NSLog(@"There is no managedObjectContext at getFetchArray");
        }
           NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        [request setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [sortDescriptors release];
        [sortDescriptor release];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
        if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
            NSLog(@"mutableFetchResults array is nil");
        } 
        [request release];

        return mutableFetchResults;
    }
```

//setting up arrayOfArrays

```
-(void)createArrayOfArrays {
 NSMutableArray *fetchArray = [self getFetchArray];
  NSMutableArray *todayDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *yesterdayDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *thisWeekArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //... create an array for each section you want

for (UserEntity *ue in fetchArray) {
       if(ue.lastmoddate) { //if the attribute is not nil
        if(ue.lastmoddate isEqual todayDate)
       [todayDateArray insertObject:ue atIndex:0];
     else if (ue.lastmoddate isEqual yesterdayDate)
       [yesterdayDateArray insertObject:ue atIndex:0];
        // ... do this for every section array 
        }
    }

 arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:todayDateArray,yesterdayDateArray,...(the rest of the arrays created for each attribute), nil]



  [todayDateArray release];
    [yesterdayDateArray release];
  //  ... release all the arrays except arrayOfArrays and fetchArray     
 }
```

//setting up the managedObjectContext

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];//what ever //the name of your appDel is.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        self.managedObjectContext = context;

       [self createArrayofArrays];//this first creates the arrayOfArrays and will set it //equal to anything that's saved in the database. If you add an entity you will need to update //it.
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return arrayOfArrays.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

//then displaying the cells in your table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }


        UserEntity *ent = (UserEntity *)[[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryBasic;
        if(ent.lastmoddate) { //if lastmoddate is not nil
        cell.textLabel.text = ent. lastmoddate;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"lastmoddate is nil at tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath");
        }

        NSLog(@"tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath called.");
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so here is the background.  I have a remote database that I use CoreData to connect with.  

There is a User entity and two other entities. There is a one-to-many relationships between User and the other entites.  User entity if for the Username authentication.  One of the other two is called 'Meeting'.
When a User logs in, I'm fetching all the objects in the 'Meeting' entity and displaying them in a tableViewController.  In the 'Meeting' entity, amongst other attributes (about 20), one of them is 'lastmoddate' As in last modified date of that object. This is what is being to used to sort.

Comment: So, I would like to get all the NSManagedObjects for that User in the 'Meeting" entity and sort them based on 'lastmoddate' and display with in the following sections: Today, Yesterday, Last Week,  Last Month, etc.  

When the user selects on the of the cells, another UITableViewController will pull up displaying all the values for the attributes in that object.

Comment: Oh wow..you wrote a detailed reply as I was typing the above comments. Let me review.  Thanks.

Comment: oh ok, im going to make a few changes then

Comment: it's midnight here.  I'll get back you in the AM.  Thank you so very much for your assistance.

Comment: np, i made the changes so it should work for wat you need. Just copy and past and then there are a few changes you have to make, like for example i didn't know the name of your appDelegate so i just wrote appDelegate and then commented beside it